# Is it possible to add vms in a particular group with virtualbox vagrant provider?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have several vms in my virtualbox. Instead of a single list in ui, i would like to see them in different groups. so all the machines of a particular environment will be grouped together. is it possible , to mention group name in vagrantfile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible. Notice from VirtualBox manual:

> --groups , ...: This changes the group membership of a VM. Groups always start with a / and can be nested. By default VMs are in group /.

Just do like that:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--groups", "/mygroupname"]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I did not try but I assume the following should work

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--groups", "mygroupname"]
end
```